# Add a space after auto-completing reply address

Tags: feature-request, comments, autocomplete

I've noticed that I don't always get a reply notification.  I think this is because the end user isn't always hitting the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar after the "@" auto-complete function is enacted.

That is, when replying to someone, hitting the @ sign and then a couple letters, you will get that little "pop-up" that shows the auto-complete name.  Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> completes the user's name, but it places the cursor directly behind the last character, so that if they don't press the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar before typing the reply, it messes up the user name and no reply is received:

> @LarsTechYou never answered me...

Yes, the end user should be a little more careful.

But it seems like a simple little enhancement to just add a space after auto-completing the name so that the cursor is already in position to start typing the actual message and it helps avoid the inadvertent missed reply.

Comment: I needthat featureon mycomputer keyboardalso.

Answer (score 2):

No, thanks. For one, I like to use a comma, which is [perfectly supported too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020):

> - Single trailing punctuation such as a dot, comma or colon is ignored, like *@name, yes* works, but *@name... no* does not.

Some others prefer a colon.

And I often *end* a comment with *@name* if the comment is not just for that user, but I still want to trigger a notification:

> This implies that I have to delete an automatic space here, @LarsTech.

Adding a space implies that people who *do* type carefully need to delete that. To me, though the advantage is for the one being notified, that feels like favoring those who don't care about formatting.

Comment: Fair argument.  I didn't think about other punctuations.